# When I put multiple variables in SELECT section, the GROUP BY section does not work

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table looks as below:

**storeHistory table**

| InventoryID | InventoryDate | InventoryAmount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2014-06-01 | 20 |
| 2 | 2014-06-15 | 45 |
| 3 | 2014-07-01 | 31 |
| 4 | 2014-07-15 | 24 |
| 5 | 2014-08-01 | 54 |
| 6 | 2014-08-15 | 76 |
| 7 | 2014-09-01 | 91 |
| 8 | 2014-09-15 | 24 |
| 9 | 2015-06-01 | 56 |
| 10 | 2015-06-15 | 82 |

**I wish to get inventory amount for different month and year**

-- trail one

```
SELECT InventoryAmount,
    YEAR(InventoryDate) AS Year, 
    MONTH(InventoryDate) AS Month
FROM storeHistory
GROUP BY Year AND Month
HAVING COUNT (InventoryAmount);
```

This leads to the following error:

> Error Code: 1055.Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column storeHistory.InventoryAmount which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by...```

--trail two

```
SELECT COUNT(InventoryAmount) as Amount
FROM storeHistory
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(InventoryDate, '%Y-%m-%d ');
```

However, this does not work either.

Comment: exactly what error said, that's something that have changed in some version of MySQL - you can either change your query or MySQL settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using this version, going by your current two queries which are almost correct:

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(InventoryDate, '%Y-%m') ym, SUM(InventoryAmount) AS Amount
FROM storeHistory
GROUP BY ym;
```

Both of your two attempts have various problems.  The rule of thumb for `GROUP BY` queries is that every column appearing in the `SELECT` clause has to either be an aggregate, such as `SUM()`, or must also appear in `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

Your query contains actually a few errors:

- Columns in `GROUP BY` are separated by comma, not `AND`.
- You need to aggregate (for instance `SUM`) all columns that you don't group.
- Your `HAVING` clause does not make sense. So I removed it. `HAVING` is the `WHERE` clause for groups.

```
SELECT SUM(InventoryAmount)
       YEAR(InventoryDate) AS Year, 
       MONTH(InventoryDate) AS Month
FROM storeHistory
GROUP BY Year, Month;
```